# Do we say "stocks" when we refer to stocks in general?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

> But stock can become plural when used synecdochically to refer to a
>   stock market, a portfolio, or a segment of a market—for example

Found the above, but it didn't cover the example when we speak of stocks in general as in:

> Stocks can go up and down in value.

I am wondering, because I have difficulty of expressing the idea without using "stock" in plural, so I am assuming it's another case that wasn't covered in the quote above.

Comment: This is a very confusing question. First, your quoted source is lacking context. Second, you seem to be interpreting the quotation as being inconsistent with your own example, but I do not see any inconsistency. Where do you see an inconsistency? Please edit your question so that it is not closed for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a case of referring to the market as a whole.

I think of it as being equivalent to "any given stock can...", expressing a general principle.

I don't know what a proper grammarian would say, but I would say stock is uncountable or countable depending on the use case. In the countable singular, it means "stock of a given type", whether in a given company, or a category or whatever. In that case, you might say "two different stocks", or "tech stocks" (the matter being a segment of the market).